# Sendgrid SMTP Symfony Switfmailer

Tags: symfony, smtp, sendgrid

Trying to use Sendgrid's SMTP on Symfonys Switfmailer with the following parameters:

```
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: smtp.sendgrid.net
mailer_user: apikey
mailer_password: THE_API_KEY
```

Whenever I test it I get no errors, but also no emails come out.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't the `mailer_user` be the actual username? You should probably have a look at the official swift mailer example https://github.com/sendgrid/smtpapi-php/blob/master/examples/swift_mailer.php

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem many many times; here's how I usually debug it:

1. Check your logs to see if the email is actually being sent within the application.
2. Check your service providers logs to see if it's being triggered there; I generally use mailgun, and they have a list of "events" that were triggered, so I can see if an email was fired, and to which address.
3. Are you testing emails to a valid domain? Swiftmailer uses validation that will fail if you attempt to send to an "invalid" domain, even if you're using `disable_delivery` with `delivery_addresses`
4. Most configurations require the `mailer_user` to be the actual "sent from" email address; again mailgun as an example uses `postmaster@yourdomain.com` as the "username" and the password is generally not the API key or API password.

Comment: Will try changing the mailer_user. As for checking the server log, I am using gmail to test, not sure I can view such logs there.

Comment: you can check the logs in your app: `/app/var/logs/`